# Adafruit MPR121 - Read/write threshold value

Tags: python, readwrite

Please could you help me to work out how to change the threshold on the MPR121 using circuit python?

The code is here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MPR121

By editing the example I have been able to read values in the MPR121 class using: mpr121.[function name]. However the threshold values seem to be in a different class, and I can't work out how to read them (nevermind change them).

I think this should be simple and I'm missing something, any ideas?

Thank you!